# SQLite, leap year check, and day counting

Tags: sqlite, leap-year

I am trying to write some sqlite code that will check if the date range include February 29th and if so, divide the total number of days elapsed by 366.  Otherwise, divide by 365.    I've only included one of the two queries as fixing one essentially fixes the other.

Thank you for your help.

```
 UPDATE table SET "Date Adjust" = (strftime('%Y-%m-%d',"End Date") - 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d',"Start Date"))/366
    WHERE "2020-02-29" BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d',"Start Date") AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',"End Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the difference in days between 2 dates you should not subtract the result of `strftime()`.
The function `strftime()` returns a formatted date as a string.

You can use the function [`julianday()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET "Date Adjust" = 
  (julianday('%Y-%m-%d',"End Date") - julianday('%Y-%m-%d',"Start Date")) / 
  (365 + ("2020-02-29" BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d', "Start Date") AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d', "End Date")))
```

The value returned by `julianday()` is a floating point number, so if you want the result as an integer you may round it with the function `ROUND()`.

For this statement to work your dates must be in the only valid date format for SQLite which is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

The above statement will work for both cases: leap year or not.

Comment: Thanks.  However it isn't working.  Other, simpler functions work fine, so something isn't right in the function though I can't figure out what.  The dates are text in mm/dd/yyyy format in case that is relevant

Comment: Realized my issue.  Making a new thread as it's an entirely different problem

Comment: @HelpWithR you can't apply SQLite date functions to dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy. The only valid date format in SQLite is YYYY-MM-DD.